# AutoGK and 100% CPU Usage

Tags: video, conversion

So, my question is this. When I'm using AutoGK to convert from .VOB to .AVI my CPU maxes out between 95%-100%. Will this affect the final output video with things such as stuttering and what not? If not, how come when I encode .AVI to a DVD with Nero and it maxes out my CPU, does the final result come out crappy?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system performance, transcoding can be very processor intensive.  I wouldn't necessarily co-relate the video quality with the transcoder maxing the CPU out.  I transcode to AVI and MP4 on a Pentium III 800 and it works great, it's just slow.

Comment: I'm not worried about how long it takes, I'm just worried that because it's maxing out that it will affect the final quality.

Comment: I understand your concern, but it should not affect final quality.

Comment: Any idea what the problem is with transcoding from AVI to DVD then?